# Remove square brackets [] from method GET form url

Tags: php, forms, get

I'm using a form with method GET and a checkbox array:

```
foreach ($foo AS $key=> $value) {
$i++;
echo '<label for="'.$i.'">'.$value.'</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="'.$value.'"" />';
}
```

which outputs a url like:

```
form.php?id=34&foo[]=c1&foo[]=c2&foo[]=c3
```

is there a way to remove the square brackets `[]` other then changing the forms method to POST which is not really and option?

Comment: Don't name the element `foo[]`, but `foo`...

Comment: what is wrong with the square brackets? if you remove them, you will get only the last value in the get string. in the url you provided, you will only get $_GET['foo']=='c3'.

Comment: Since you are generating checkboxes in a loop, you have to keep that brackets, otherwise one checkbox value will be overwritten by another

Comment: Jonathan and Kasun both point to the reason you need square brackets. Is there a compelling reason you want to get rid of them?

Comment: No, no real compelling reason other then "pretty" urls really.

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you want multiple possible values to be allowed and to have it as a single array to work with on the PHP side that corresponds to the check boxes, it needs to be named with the brackets.  Normally this isn't an issue as you typically submit forms with posts and don't see the arguments.

Comment: form method was originally POST but I changed it to GET to fix a previous problem.

Comment: @AnnaRiekic Create a question about the previous problem... maybe we can help you get it working with a POST.